# Factor of 3 in Photon Diffusion coefficient

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, diffusion

From definition of Diffusion coefficient:
$$D = c/3(\mu_a+\mu_s),$$
where $c$ is the speed of light front, $\mu_a$ is absorption coefficient and $\mu_s$ is scattering coefficient.

I wonder where does factor of $1/3$ comes from? I assume it is coming from dimensionality, but I didn't find arguments proving that.
UPD:
In this question I refer to diffusion approximation of Radiation Transfer Equation also known as Photon Diffusion Equation.

Comment: Diffusion of what?  Please give a reference as to where your formula comes from, and what it is supposed to apply to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_transfer_equation_and_diffusion_theory_for_photon_transport_in_biological_tissue) is some information about this. The factor comes from an approximation and using spherical harmonics.

Answer (score 0):

The factor of three enters from the flux equation during the derivation. Not a full answer, but this was too large for a comment.

See here equation 5.

[image: diffusion screenshot]

Comment: Do I understand it right that it depends on dimensionality of a problem, 2D, 3D, etc?